# Toggle button back to default html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the innerHTML of my button back to default. It works with changing the innerHTML the first time, but then I can't get it back to default.

I've tried using booleans to toggle back and forth, but my code just won't execute the second part of the function.

```js
function money() {
  var money = document.getElementById('money');
  var text = "normal";

  if (text == "normal") {
    money.innerHTML = "<h1>Let me ask you</h1><p>Does this work<p>";
    text = "changed";
  } else {
    money.innerHTML = "<h1>Money Laundering</h1><p>Click For More Info</p>";
    text = "normal";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="practiceContainer">
  <h1 id="practiceHeader">Practice Areas</h1>
  <div class="lawgrid">
    <button class="practicesBox" id="money" onclick="money()">
      <h1>Money Laundering</h1>
      <p>Click For More Info</p>
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

I expected my code to change back to default html, but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `text` variable to `"normal"` at the beginning of the function, therefore when your code reaches  your `if` logic, `text` will always be `"normal"`.

Consider simply moving the `text` variable *outside* of your function, so that it doesn't keep resetting with each click.

```js
var text = "normal";
var btnMoney = document.getElementById('money');

function money() {
  if (text == "normal") {
    btnMoney.innerHTML = "<h1>Let me ask you</h1><p>Does this work<p>";
    text = "changed";
  } else {
    btnMoney.innerHTML = "<h1>Money Laundering</h1><p>Click For More Info</p>";
    text = "normal";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="practiceContainer">
  <h1 id="practiceHeader">Practice Areas</h1>
  <div class="lawgrid">
    <button class="practicesBox" id="money" onclick="money()">
      <h1>Money Laundering</h1>
      <p>Click For More Info</p>
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should've known that as soon as it fulfills either the if or the else if in an if/else statement that it exits the function entirely and re-reads the function from the beginning when you re-click again.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Note that functions don't exit early due to `if/else` conditions, but in your case, that's the end of your function :)